# Pagination with CodeIgniter removes 'link' of the database tables

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following address in CodeIgniter:

```
/movprod/countries/movies-produced-in-the-united-states-dh88075452
```

With pagination **'movies-produced-in-the-united-states-dh88075452'** is removed: 
`/movprod/countries/10`, for example
what causes error because I need the last 4 numbers (id of the table) to get the data from the database.
How do I keep the link?

Comment: Can You share Your pagination configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter pagination has many configs, one of them is the segment which it will take as number of page, by default is "3" you need to change it to "4".

in the pagination config use:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

As you can see here:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html